# VirtualBox install of Ubuntu stuck on wallpaper

Tags: 15.04, virtualbox

Good evening,

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 as a VirtualBox guest machine. After entering my username and password it:

- remains on the wallpaper
- no task bar
- mouse cursor works, but neither left nor right mouse buttons seem to work

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong and how to fix my installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: English, please!

Comment: Askubuntu is a site where the main language is English so asking your question in a different language will probably reduce your chance on getting an answer. Please consider translating your question.

Comment: How much RAM the guest and host have?
keep in mind that Ubuntu 15.05 [requires a minimum of 1.5GB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal by pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

And then `reboot` your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: If the icons & then rest of Unity aren't showing, AFAIK that key sequence won't work.